# Python - common function for creating links for FILES and DIRECTORIES?

Tags: python, python-3.x, symlink

In python we are creating links with `os.symlink` function for directories.

```
os.symlink(src, destination)
```

When we tried to create links for files we got for file extension **.symlink** instead of their real etxensions (**.txt, .exe**...)

So for those files we had to run function `os.link`

```
os.link(src, destination)
```

My question is if we can use some single common function in Python that will create us proper links for both cases - files and dirs (including the correct extension for the files). This is executed on windows server.

Thank you!

Comment: Python on a sane OS doesn't do anything like that; I'm guessing you are on some horrible platform like Windows?

Comment: @tripleee true, Windows, but I cannot change it as that is customer server

Comment: My condolences; perhaps [edit] your question to clarify these miserable circumstances.